# Javascript deleteRow causing indexSizeError, need closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have this code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("editTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var i = row.rowIndex;

var remove = document.createElement("input");
    remove.type = "button";
    remove.value = "Remove";
    remove.onclick = (function() {
        var I = i;
        return function() {
            table.deleteRow(I);
        }
    })();

var td1 = row.insertCell(-1);
td1.appendChild(remove);
```

I have read several articles here and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. When I try to delete the last row that I create , I get this error:

```
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
table.deleteRow(I);
```

I am pretty sure this is a closure issue. I understand scope but not syntax for anonymous functions in javascript;

Comment: Are you trying to remove the data above the Remove button?

Comment: I have a table inside a form (an invoice) that I set up (thanks to you wonderful people on this forum) to create a row for labor or parts charges. I want each row I create to have a button that deletes the row. I'm not worried about passing the indexes after submit as in PHP, the indexes won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over thinking the whole function/anonymous function/closure stuff here. It's looking a little too complicated. Try this code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("editTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);

var remove = document.createElement("input");
//Append input first so you can get it's parent
var td1 = row.insertCell(-1)
             .appendChild(remove);

remove.type = "button";
remove.value = "Remove";

remove.onclick = function () {
    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode; //get the row node
    table.deleteRow(parent.rowIndex - 1); //Delete the row index behind it.
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/XFXFA/1/)

Comment: That deletes other fields I statically added to the form

Comment: But I tinkered with it and I believe the line: var td1 = row.insertCell(-1).appendChild(remove); is the fix. I tried this before but as td1 = insertCell(-1); td1.appendChild(remove); Not sure what the difference is but it works! and I removed -1 from table.deleteRow(parent.rowIndex - 1);

Answer (score 1):

Corey, I see you have a working solution but you may be interested in something closer to your original idea.

The problem with your original code appears to be that `i` becomes an unreliable measure of current row index after other rows have been removed. Trapping `i` in a closure is not a solution - you just trap a value that is guaranteed to be correct only at the time it is trapped.

However trapping `row` itself, then obtaining `row.rowIndex` when it's needed will be reliable, because `row.rowIndex` gives the *current* index, not the index at the time the row was appended to the table.

```
remove.onclick = (function(row) {
    return function() {
        table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
    };
})(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code working:

```
var remove = document.createElement("input");
    remove.type = "button";
    remove.value = "Remove";
    remove.onclick = function () {
        var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode; //get the row node
        table.deleteRow(parent.rowIndex); //Delete the row index behind it.
    };

    var td1 = row.insertCell(-1)
         .appendChild(remove);
```